# First lambda capture of local variable always False

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

Connecting a lambda function to a Qt widget, lambda needs to capture two local variables and pass them to an external function. I'm having an issue that's stumping me because it is definitely positional:

```
pushbutton.clicked.connect(lambda ca=current_answer, a=correct_answer:
            self.ap.parse_answer(ca, a))
```

passes `(False, "desired correct_answer string")`, while switching the order of the local variable captures:

```
pushbutton.clicked.connect(lambda a=correct_answer,ca=current_answer:
            self.ap.parse_answer(ca, a))
```

passes `("desired current_answer string", False)`

Whichever variable I capture first is always set to False while the second variable capture is always what is intended.

This suggests that there isn't something else in my code assigning False to either `current_answer` or `correct_answer`, and a print() statement inserted immediately prior to calling the lambda function confirms that both variables are set to the desired strings. Maybe I'm just not capturing the variables correctly, but after doing some reading I can't find any issue with my syntax. My variable captures look the same as numerous examples I have found.

Comment: try printing the `repr` of the strings, there may well be something you cannot see

Comment: @ Padraic Cunningham: Thanks for the suggestion, but the repr of both strings is just the intended string.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a self-contained way (ideally one that's independent of Qt)?

Comment: what does code for self.ap.parse_answer look like?  Is it missing a required self argument?

Comment: @BrenBarn: I'm attempting to do so now.

Comment: Does Qt itself pass extra arguments to the callback? They could clobber your captures.

Comment: Also, note that what you "capture" with your defaults could be overridden when the callback is actually called.

Comment: @dansalmo: parse_answer() is an if statement comparing the two strings which conditionally calls additional functions. parse_answer() is currently is receiving all required positional arguments. I have verified that the False is genuinely being passed to the parse_answer().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are always seeing `False` as the first argument passed in to your callback lambda because Qt defines the signal [`QAbstractButton::clicked`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked) to take a single argument with a default value of `False`. Since your lambda is handling that signal, it gets called with `False`.

For the benefit of others: because the lambda gets called only with a single argument, the second and third parameters get their default values, which the OP has now defined as the values of the in-scope variables `answer` and `current_answer`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it's just the following:

When we define default arguments in the function definition `f(keyword=default...)` but in the call we don't explicitly state `keyword=value` then it cares about order of arguments, even if they appear to match the keyword.  So I believe your `lambda` function cares about the order of what it's receiving, not the default values you're assigning.  In your first example, `ca` gets whatever the first argument is being sent to `lambda` and `a` gets whatever the second one is.  In your second example `a` gets whatever the first argument is and `ca` gets whatever the second one is.  The fact that you've defined default values for them isn't doing anything, unless whatever is calling the `lambda` is sending it nothing.

If I define a function

```
def f(a=1,b=2):
    return (a,b)
```

and then call it as

```
a=True
b=False
(x,y) = f(a,b)
```

I'll find `x=True`, `b=False`

but if instead I call it as

```
a=True
b=False
(x,y) = f(b,a)
```

I'll find `x=False`, `b=True` because when I call it this way it understands that the first argument of the call is `a` and the second is `b`.

If I use the third option (which is what I think you're anticipating)

```
(x,y) = f(b=False, a=True)
```

then I get `x=True`, `y=False`.  I think this is the behavior you thought you would get.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but the issue seems to have something to do with Qt going over the lambda captures. At no time in my code do I explicitly set either of the variables to be captures to a boolean.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting you ever explicitly set either variable to be a boolean.  I could have just as easily used `3` and `4` instead of `True` and `False` in my example.  The point was that whatever was calling the `lambda` function was sending it arguments.  Those arguments were going to overwrite whatever the defaults were that you tried to assign.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments of BrenBarn and Lambda Fairy I decided to assume Qt was resetting the value of the first argument to False.

As a work-around, I added a third positional argument to ap.parse_answer, and had the lambda expression capture a trivial local variable before capturing the two vital variables:

```
pushbutton.clicked.connect(lambda sacrificial="",a=answer,ca=current_answer: 
                                      self.ap.parse_answer(sacrificial, ca, a))
```

The variable that Qt writes over just gets ignored by the called function, and the code works.

If I add a print(sacrificial_variable) call to ap.parse_answer(), not surprisingly its value is False.

Comment: Given this, why send lambda arguments with defaults at all?  Just do  `lambda x : self.ap.parse_answer(current_answer, correct_answer)`

Comment: @Joel: I'm creating multiple pushbuttons iteratively with different functions connected to them. My code originally had it they way you suggest, but that connects the same function (the final one generated) to all pushbuttons created.

Comment: just be careful with your approach - if any call would ever send two arguments, your `a` would get overwritten again.

Comment: @Jefe - ah, you were hitting this bug: http://math.andrej.com/2009/04/09/pythons-lambda-is-broken/ - hmm, I thought this was fixed in Python 3.

Comment: The `sacrificial` argument is called `checked`: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked - it indicates whether the button is checked (i.e. with a checkmark) or not.

Comment: @Yawar: Thanks for the info; behavior now understood. If you submit that as an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: @Jefe - thanks :-) I've submitted an answer, hope it is well-phrased.